# Pick 3 random strings, and then split them with a comma in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, split

I have been searching for a little bit, but I was not able to find anything that was worth while. So here is my problem:
I have quite a long string that I want to pick 3 random sets out of, and then split the 3 strings by a comma. Here is the relevant code:

```
$mapsandmodes = array("Raid - Hardpoint", "Raid - Capture The Flag", "Raid - Search and Destroy", "Plaza - Hardpoint", "Plaza - Capture The Flag", "Aftermath - Search and Destroy", "Express - Capture The Flag", "Express - Hardpoint", "Express - Search and Destroy", "Meltdown - Search and Destroy", "Slums - Search and Destroy", "Slums - Hardpoint", "Slums - Capture The Flag", "Standoff - Capture The Flag", "Standoff - Search and Destroy", "Yemen - Hardpoint");
```

I tried using `$mapswithmodes = array_rand($mapsandmodes)`,but that outputs a number(I have gotten "1" and "2" so far). I want it to choose 3 random sets of strings for that long line and then split the 3 by commas so that I can put it into a MYSQL table.

Comment: Instead of 'split the 3 by commas' surely you mean 'join the three by commas'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to pick three random elements without replacement (e.g. you will never pick the same one twice):

step 1) shuffle the array http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

step 2) grab the first three elements of the array

step 3) use implode to join them into one string with comma as glue http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

If you want to pick three random elements with replacement (e.g. you can pick the same one twice):

step 1) call array_rand($mapsandmodes) three times. this gives you an index for the array. $mapsandmodes[array_rand($mapsandmodes)] will therefore give a random value in the array.

step 2) use implode

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know how to shuffle the array and how to implode strings, but how do you "grab the first three elements of the array"?

Comment: Make a new array and add to it $mapsandmodes[0], $mapsandmodes[1], $mapsandmodes[2] using the `[]` operator -> if you do something like $array[] = newvalue then it gets inserted onto the end of the array.

Comment: $mapsandmodes[0] for the first one etc

Comment: Alright. So I added this to my code:
    "shuffle($mapsandmodes);
  foreach ($mapsandmodes as $mwithm) {
      echo "$mwithm";
  }
  $mandm = array($mwithm[0], $mwithm[1], $mwithm[2]);
  implode(",", $mandm);"
It is showing $mwithm at the top of my page, and showing $mandm as "Array". Im a bit confused with that and then how would I assign a variable so that I can upload it to my MYSQL Table? Sorry for being so php-illiterate with this.

Comment: @Patashu Read the updated version. Sorry. I failed the first time

Comment: @user2133895 $randommodestring = implode(",", $mandm); Then do an SQL query that inserts that as part of it.

Comment: @Patashu With the code you put there, I am getting the first three letters(I go "S,t,a").

Comment: @user2133895 Ah, I re-read it. That's because you're taking the first, second and third letters of $mwithm rather than the first, second and third entries of $mapsandmodes, e.g. $mapsandmodes[0] $mapsandmodes[1] $mapsandmodes[2]

Comment: Do you have skype because this is becoming an extended conversation. My skype is rastrocn. If not, whatever. How would I go about select the first three words instead of letters?

Comment: $mandm = array($mapsandmodes[0], $mapsandmodes[1], $mapsandmodes[2]);

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to shuffle, the problem with your original code is just misunderstanding array_rand(): [array_rand() doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

```
$optionkeys = array_rand($mapsandmodes, 3);
```

then $optionkeys will be an array with length 3 who's values are the keys chosen from the original array, and you can access the strings in order with $mapsandmodes[($optionkeys[0])], $mapsandmodes[($optionkeys[1])], and $mapsandmodes[($optionkeys[2])].